# how to prevent duplicate values while using inner for loop in oracle plsql?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am passing c1 value as param to the c2,c3 cursor's , so i am getting duplicate values and how to write better than this code using plsql code?

```
Declare
      cursor cur1;
      cursor  cur2
      is
      select * from 
      where param=c1.param;

      cursor  cur3
      is
      select * from 
      where param=c1.param;
    Begin
       for c1 loop
         for c2(c1.param)
           dbms_output(deptno||' '||dname);
          for c3(c1.param)
           dbms_output(deptno||' '||dname);
          end loop;
        end loop;
       end loop;
    End;

    So , i am getting duplicate values 

    deptno  dname
    10       a
    20       b
    30       c
    10       a
    20       b
    30       c
Expected output as
    deptno  dname
    10       a
    20       b
    30       c
```

can you please help me?

Comment: Is there any reason for you to think you need _nested_ loops here ?

Comment: hi, didn't get your point, can you please explain me please? and give me better solution on this

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may want a UNION:

```
Declare
  cursor cur1;

  cursor  cur2 is
     select * from X
     where param=c1.param
     union
     select * from Y
     where param=c1.param;
Begin
   for c1 loop
     for c2(c1.param)
       dbms_output(deptno||' '||dname);
      end loop;
   end loop;
End;
```

(I haven't fixed your invalid code above - presumably your real code is correct or it wouldn't have run at all.)

You probably don't need even 2 cursors, you could do something like:

```
Declare
  cursor  cur is
     select * from X
     where param in (select ...)
     union
     select * from Y
     where param in (select ...)
Begin
   for c2 in cur loop
      dbms_output(deptno||' '||dname);
   end loop;
End;
```

Comment: Thank U Tony , i want to pass c2 column as a param to get another column data , so that's y i used 3 separate cursor's

Comment: multiple table used in c1,c2,c3 cursor's

Comment: Hi, if i use union for the c2,c3cursor how can i take 2 different columns from both cursor's

Comment: You can't - unless there is a 1:1 correspondence between them e.g. `select a_code, a_desc from a union select b_code, b_desc from b`

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use inner join to avoid cursor looping.
2. use distinct keyword to get distinct value.
3. user of rownum keword to get only one row.
4. eliminate duplicate by group by clause.